# date.parse not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I wanted to parse date to time stamp. So I used following code to convert date to timestamp.

```
var d = "2010-12-17";
var ts = Date.parse(d)/1000;
console.log(ts);
```

This working fine except safari. How can I use timestamp in Safari.?

I tried using moment.js, but when I checked the output the result showing one day before. I have no idea why that is. But today date is perfectly working with moment.js.

Comment: Have you tried `var ts = moment(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()/1000;`?

Comment: @Saptal it is giving me wrong value.

Comment: Did you try `var ts = moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("X")`?

Comment: `X` is the token used by moment to format date as Unix Timestamp, you can find docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: @VincenzoC that is the way I tried. It is giving me no error but when I convert the unix value to date it is not the date I converted.

Comment: @user2584538 how do you convert the unix value to date? Maybe you can add code to your question, including your attemps using moment.js. Anyway you can try `var ts = moment.utc(d, "YYYY-MM-DD")` to parse your date as UTC instead of local time.

Comment: @VincenzoC this is the way I am using.
var d = "2015-12-12";
var guideDate = moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD").unix(); 
but when I convert unix value into date it is showing me 2015-12-11

Comment: Sorry @user2584538 but the code to convert the unix value to date is still missing. Did you try with `moment.utc`?

Comment: I checked with online converter. no actually i didn't check with moment.utc so far.